# LINQ Join not returning results if second or third table empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, join

I've three tables :

```
Module_Articles_Articles
Module_Articles_Categories
Module_Articles_Comments
```

and I want to display my articles in repeater my query :

```
var articles =
                (from a in context.Module_Articles_Articles
                 join c in context.Module_Articles_Categories on a.CategoryID equals c.CategoryID
                 join co in context.Module_Articles_Comments on a.ArticleID equals co.ArticleID
                 where a.IsDraft == false
                 orderby a.ArticleID descending
                 select new
                 {
                     a.ArticleID,
                     a.ArticleTitle,
                     a.ArticleContent,
                     a.Image,
                     a.Sender,
                     a.SentDate,
                     a.Summary,
                     a.Likes,
                     a.Dislikes,
                     a.Tags,
                     a.PostMode,
                     c.CategoryID,
                     c.CategoryTitle,
                     AcceptedCommentsCount = 
                     (from com in context.Module_Articles_Comments where com.ArticleID == a.ArticleID && com.Status select com)
                     .Count(),
                     DeniedCommentsCount =
                     (from com in context.Module_Articles_Comments where com.ArticleID == a.ArticleID 
                          && com.Status == false select com)
                     .Count()
                 }).ToList();
```

but when `Module_Articles_Categories` or `Module_Articles_Comments` are empty my query returns nothing!
Is my code true? If not, how can I do this?

Comment: i think you need to add `LINQ` tag to your question to get quick answers.

Comment: I updated your title to question, very uninformative before...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you want an OUTTER JOIN, which can be accomplished in a query like this by simply adding `.DefaultIfEmpty()`

```
from a in context.Module_Articles_Articles
join c in context.Module_Articles_Categories on a.CategoryID equals c.CategoryID into ca
from c in cs.DefaultIfEmpty()
join co in context.Module_Articles_Comments on a.ArticleID equals co.ArticleID into com
from co in com.DefaultIfEmpty()
where a.IsDraft == false
orderby a.ArticleID descending
select new ...
```

Comment: step through the code, when the breakpoint hits this line it will be turned into a SQL statement (assuming your using SQL Server) and  run the sql  directly in your database and see if it is returning results there, or actually post the sql that is getting generated

Comment: how to get generated sql syntax?

Comment: ok, actually I just updated code, there were a couple syntax errors, try it now , then I'll tell you how to get generated SQL

Answer (score 3):

You are not getting results because your LINQ joins result in `INNER JOIN`s. You probably want `LEFT JOIN`s. Do it as follows.

```
var articles =
    (from a in context.Module_Articles_Articles
     join c in context.Module_Articles_Categories on a.CategoryID equals c.CategoryID into joinTable1
     from c in joinTable1.DefaultIfEmpty()
     join co in context.Module_Articles_Comments on a.ArticleID equals co.ArticleID into joinTable2
     from co in joinTable2.DefaultIfEmpty()
     where a.IsDraft == false
     orderby a.ArticleID descending
     select new
     {
         a.ArticleID,
         a.ArticleTitle,
         a.ArticleContent,
         a.Image,
         a.Sender,
         a.SentDate,
         a.Summary,
         a.Likes,
         a.Dislikes,
         a.Tags,
         a.PostMode,
         c.CategoryID,
         c.CategoryTitle,
         AcceptedCommentsCount = 
         (from com in context.Module_Articles_Comments where com.ArticleID == a.ArticleID && com.Status select com)
         .Count(),
         DeniedCommentsCount =
         (from com in context.Module_Articles_Comments where com.ArticleID == a.ArticleID 
              && com.Status == false select com)
         .Count()
     }).ToList();
```